# Trying to sort output of mailbox sized

Tags: bash, sort, csv

Trying to sort an output file of mailbox sizes.

```
user1@example.com, 1.35 MB
user2@example.com, 2.19 GB
user3@eexample.com, 0 B
userxyz@example.com, 0 B
userabc@example.com, 1.66 MB
test1@example.com, 0 B
example@example.com, 47.84 KB
test2@example.com, 1.28 MB
user1@example.com, 1.76 MB
```

I have searched the forum, but I always get file sizes from `ls` output.  This is numerical strings.

What I tried:

```
sort -k 2,3 mailbox-size.csv
```

My goal is to eventually find the "average" size, but just trying to sort the list at this point.

Comment: What is the command that generate this CSV output?

Comment: It's a zmprov export from zimbra, then I use awk to filter out just the address, and mailbox size. 

ie: cat sizes-all.txt | awk '{ print $4", "$6, $7 }'

Comment: The original export commands run: 
all_accounts=`zmprov -l gaa`; for account in $all_accounts; do mbox_size=`zmmailbox -z -m $account gms`; echo "Mailbox size of $account = $mbox_size"; done ;

Comment: Search an option in `zmprov export` to output sizes as bytes and non human readable format

Comment: Gosh, I wish that was an option. The utility that reports the size is zmmailbox. and it has no options to format output that I know of, so I always have to massage it a little.  I could re-run the data dump, but it takes 3 full days to churn through 65K mailboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between the value and the unit to get a more conventional human readable string and you can use the  [`-h, --human-numeric-sort`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) flags in `sort`.

```
awk '{print $1 " " $2 $3}' mailbox-size.csv > mailbox-size-2.csv
sort -h -k 2 mailbox-size-2.csv

test1@example.com, 0B
user3@eexample.com, 0B
userxyz@example.com, 0B
example@example.com, 47.84KB
test2@example.com, 1.28MB
user1@example.com, 1.35MB
userabc@example.com, 1.66MB
user1@example.com, 1.76MB
user2@example.com, 2.19GB
```

Using [`numfmt`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/numfmt.1.html) you can then optionally convert the human readable strings back to numbers to facilitate further math.

```
numfmt --from=iec --suffix B --field=2 < mailbox-size-2.csv | sed s/B$//

user1@example.com, 1415578
user2@example.com, 2351494595
user3@eexample.com, 0
userxyz@example.com, 0
userabc@example.com, 1740637
test1@example.com, 0
example@example.com, 48989
test2@example.com, 1342178
user1@example.com, 1845494
```

The `sed s/B$//` command is used to remove the trailing `B` byte suffix to leave only integer byte counts to facilitate further math.

Comment: Thanks HBruijn, that works perfect for this.

Comment: Can I use numfmt to convert back to MB/GB?  Since I know someone will ask when I give them the data.

Comment: numfmt --to=iec to convert back to iec format.

Comment: Good to see that the answer is working and solves your problem @dj423 - Please also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for the etiquette on Stack Exchange sites.